# which function in 'Ion Auth' returns all the users who are members from the 'users' table using CI v3.1.3

Tags: authentication, codeigniter-3

I am unable to figure out as to which function in 'Ion Auth' returns all the users who are members from the 'users' table?I am using Ion Auth in Codeigniter v3.1.3 in WAMP.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$qry = $this->ion_auth->users();
```

you can then use `$qry->result();` or `$qry->num_rows();` etc.

if you want to do some filtering you can use

```
$qry = $this->ion_auth->where('email', 'abc@xyz.com')->users();
```